# Terminology: reversing the order of the generators.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, group-presentation

Let $H=\langle Y\mid S\rangle$ be a finite group. Then, for all $h\in H$, we can write

$$h=y_1^{\eta_1}\dots y_m^{\eta_m}$$

for some finite $m\in\Bbb N$ and finite $\eta_i\in\Bbb Z$, for $y_i\in Y$.

> Is there a name for $h^{\leftarrow}$ such that $$h^{\leftarrow}=y_m^{\eta_m}\dots y_1^{\eta_1};$$ that is, the product of $y_i^{\eta_i}$, where $i$ runs through $\{1,\dots, m\}$ in descending (rather than ascending) order?

I do realise that this definition depends on the choice of $Y$.

Comment: I have seen this as $b(y_1^{\eta_1}\dots y_m^{\eta_m})=y_m^{\eta_m}\dots y_1^{\eta_1}$ with "b" like reading backwards. For example, the *trace class" is invariant under reading backwards.

Comment: It seems that this should depend on the choice of representation $h=y_1^{\nu_1}\cdots y_m^{\nu_m}$, but I'm struggling to find an example where this choice matters. Does this choice matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is called "reversal" of $h$, see for example in the article [Trace polynomials in special linear groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9EEC03B46C19332440E63A2E9E541031/S1446788700012544a.pdf/trace_polynomials_of_words_in_special_linear_groups.pdf) by Southcott on page 408. He denotes it by ${\rm rev}(h)$.