# Base-10 "reverse pairs" in strings of the iterated Collatz conjecture function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

### Details:

*The following terminology is non-standard.*

> **Definition 1:** A *reverse pair* of numbers is a pair of numbers $m$ and $n$ such that, if the decimal expansion of $m$ is $$\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_k},$$ then that of $n$ is $$\overline{a_ka_{k-1}\cdots a_2a_1},$$ where $k\ge 2$.

For example, $35$ and $53$ form such a pair.

> **Definition 2:** A *string of the iterated [Collatz conjecture function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)* is a word $w$ in the alphabet $\Bbb N$ such that its alphabet members are exclusively in the order from left to right according to the Collatz conjecture function.

For example, $(5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)$ is such a string.

### The Question:

> I'm looking for numbers $N$ whose strings (starting with $N$) of the iterated Collatz conjecture function contain reverse pairs. Are they significant? How "common" are they?

### My attempt:

I found that $(35, 106, 53, \text{etc.})$ is such a string, so $35$, its double $70$, and so on, are examples. The pair $35$ and $53$ inspired this question.

I merely guess a search using some programme or another for such $N$s would yield diminishing results as candidate $N$s increase. This guess is based on my own difficulty conjuring them up in my head or on paper.

Palindromic numbers stop the iteration of the function for obvious reasons. I'll leave it to you whether or not that's cheating, though, and whether we need to make sure $m\neq n$.

Please help :)

*Disclaimer:* **I'm not trying to examine the Collatz conjecture.** I'm just curious. I am aware that this is very "base ten" in nature.

Comment: Your idea of trying to examine the Collatz conjecture using palindromic numbers is interesting, but something to keep in mind is that 35 and 53 are palindromes only because they're written in base 10. In base 12 for instance they are written as 2,11 and 4,5. Why do we only consider palindromes in base 10? I don't see any particular reason why base 10 is important for this problem specifically.

Comment: *Disclaimer:* **I'm not trying to examine the Collatz conjecture.** My questions here would be too simplistic

Comment: Neither $35$ nor $53$ are palindromic numbers, @RyanGreyling.

Comment: Oh my bad, the proper term I meant to use was reverse pairs.

Comment: See the answer to [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2612548/104041) for some idea of why I chose this definition; if there's something more standard, please let me know.

Comment: 70 doesn't go through 7.

Comment: Somewhat similar: [Particular base-10 digit patterns in Collatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949186/particular-base-10-digit-patterns-in-collatz)

Comment: "I don't see any particular reason why base 10 is important for this problem specifically"  I realize the OP isn't interested in the Collatz conjecture but as the base of $10$, itself, is $3$ times an odd number plus $1$ it reasonable to imaging that may have some minor reverberations.

Comment: Yes, @RoddyMacPhee, but $70$ is twice $35$, which goes through $53$.

Comment: I can relate most of Collatz to base conversion. 3x+1 is a shift and add 1 in base 3, and the cutting in half is a conversion of doubling parts of the number the number in base $3 \cdot 2^n$

Comment: Collatz is very base $2$ in nature, actually more natural than base $10$.